# ASP.NET Session Abandoning Unexpectantly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, data-loss

For some reason, the session is abandoning unexpectantly, and wreaking havoc in our application.  We've had the app setup to use Session and have been using it for several months with no problems.  Now, as we add additional content and store additional info in it, the Session is dumping well before the 20 minute timeout than its supposed to.  I'm at a loss for the reason why... could it be because we may be adding a lot of data in the Session (not sure of exact size)?  This is my local machine after all (Win 7, using IIS, ASP.NET 4.0, 4 GB RAM).

Or could there be other reasons for this occurrence?  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: I know that my hosting provider randomly cycles sessions on me. I had to use a session state server to maintain it or everyone would get logged out at once. Not sure if that applies here or not.

Comment: Is it losing all data or just some data?

Comment: You can see if you are just losing session, or if your entire application is dying. Add some code to Application_Start in Global (something simple, like appending a text file), and see if that happens every time you lose your session.

Comment: All data is lost.  We have a handler for Session_AcquireRequestState, and have code that checks the current user, which of course runs on every page request.  When session is null, it redirects to the logon page, which worked nicely earlier with natural session expiration...

Comment: Not yet.  But I haven't had a lot of time to look at it, and I passed off the info to others to help investigate.  Will post back once I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Session state in-proc. If this is the case then the most common reason of losing your Session is that the corresponding Application Pool recycles. Go check IIS settings on Application pool and set up Event log entries for such events. You'll find the settings in: **"Advanced settings"** of your app pool -> **"Recycling"** -> **"Generate Recycle Event Log Entry"**. Set them all to true and see if it will give you the reason of your Session State loss.

Also if you change data on given sites a lot then it will eventually trigger app pool recycling.

More ideas on app pool recycling:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net sessions are stored in the cache. If you are running out of memory then it will be dumped. You need to store the session in a database or other storage to keep it. I'll try to find a relevant link. Sessions are not meant to store tons of data!

Here is a link explaining how to use [out-of-process sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx). Basically the idea is that, by default, ASP.Net/IIS will use in-process sessions (which are fastest) but are also limited by the power/storage on the server running IIS. The alternatives are to use a session state farm or a SQL server to store sessions. These are a bit slower but offer more flexibility. You will need to take into account the ability to serialize sessions into your decision.

---

Here is an excerpt from a book I've been reading (Programming Microsoft ASP.NET 3.5 by Dino Esposito):

**Why Does My Session State Sometimes Get Lost?**

> When the working mode is InProc, the session state is mapped in the memory space of the AppDomain in which the page request is being served. In light of this, the session state is subject to process recycling and AppDomain restarts. As we discussed in Chapter 2, the ASP.NET worker process is periodically restarted to maintain an average good performance; when this happens, the session state is lost. Process recycling depends on the percentage of memory consumption and maybe the number of requests served. Although the process is cyclic, no general consideration can be made regarding the interval of the cycle. Be aware of this when designing your session-based, in-process application. As a general rule, bear in mind that the session state might not be there when you try to access it. Use exception handling or recovery techniques as appropriate for your application.
>
> In Knowledge Base article Q316148, Microsoft suggests that some antivirus software might be marking the web.config or global.asax file as modified, thus causing a new application to be started and subsequently causing the loss of the session state. This holds true also if you or your code modify the timestamp of those files. Also, any addition to or removal from the Bin directory causes the application to restart.
>
> Note: What happens to the session state when a running page hits an error? Will the current dictionary be saved or is it just lost? The state of the session is not saved if, at the end of the request, the page results in an error—that is, the GetLastError method of the Server object returns an exception. However, if in your exception handler you reset the error state by calling Server.ClearError, the values of the session are saved regularly as if no error ever occurred.